# Ubuntu bar font change after install fontforge and birdfont

Tags: fonts, top-bar

I install fontforge and birdfont from apt, and I didn't realize the font had changed.

After purge these two and `sudo apt autoremove --purge` and `sudo fc-cache -fv` font not fix.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Ubuntu 19.10:
[image]